# Is this matrix going to be real or complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, real-numbers, products

I hope that this is the right forum where to post this question (and not [here](https://stackoverflow.com/)).

I have a [Chi-Square Kernel Matrix](http://crsouza.com/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning-applications/#chisquare) (using the second version, which is positive-definite) `K` and this Matlab code:

```
[V_K,D_K] = eig(K);
d_k = diag(D_K);
ind_k = find(d_k > 1e-8);
d_k(ind_k) = d_k(ind_k).^(-1/2);
K_half = V_K*diag(d_k)*V_K';
```

`K_Half` is `K^(-1/2)`.

My question is: `K_half` is going to be real or complex (since `D_K` could be complex)?

If it's complex, then can I discard the imaginary part during the following operation?

```
W(:,i) = sqrt((p-1)/t)*K_half*e_s;
```

Where `e_s` is a bit vector and of course `p` and `t` are real.

I need this because I'm writing this code in `Eigen` and I need to know if I can declare `W` as `MatrixXf` or `MatrixXcf` (so real or complex).

Comment: I don't think it's entirely clear what your code does. But anyway why not just declare $W$ to be a complex matrix? It doesn't matter if you declare it to hold complex numbers and they all end up having zero imaginary part (which would correspond to $W$ being a real matrix).

Comment: I didn't write this code. As I wrote in the updated answer, `K_Half` is `K^(-1/2)`. Anyway, your solution is not memory efficient, since `MatrixXf` is a matirx of `std::float`, while `MatrixXcf` is a matrix of `std::complex`, which is much more expensive than the first choice.

Comment: I think that the code is pretty clear (even for a Matlab newbise as me), please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `find(d_k > 1e-8)` will only select the values that are positive, yes? So it's only computing `K^(-1/2)` for positive values, leaving the negative values unchanged. If it had just `d_k = d_k.^(-1/2)` then the answer would be "Yes, in general it can be complex", but I don't think that's the case here.

Since the `d_k > 1e-8` is probably built to avoid singular behavior, I would guess that this code was made for a case where all the eigenvalues are positive anyway (otherwise they would have used `abs`).

Comment: @AlexMeiburg You are right, I didn't think about it. However, `K` is the Chi-Square Kernel Matrix described [here](http://crsouza.com/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning-applications/#chisquare). In particular the second version is positive-definite, so that should mean that all the eigenvalues are positives. I updated the question specifying it.

Comment: Alright, then yes you're correct, you won't have any imaginary parts

Comment: Nice, good to know that then I can discard the imaginary part of `K_half` and I can declare `W` as real and not complex. If you'll post it as answer I'll chose it

Comment: @user6321 I stand by my point that the code is not entirely clear; how should someone unfamiliar with Matlab know what the second output of the function $\texttt{eig}$ is, or even what the output of $\texttt{diag}$ is? A little more information in the post couldn't have hurt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $K$ is positive definite, the eigenvalues will all be positive. Then all the their reciprocal square roots will be real, so the resulting matrix `K_half` will be real. So you can declare it to be real without any problems.